# How to #include the string that is argument of a function ?c++

Tags: c++, include

I have a hometask in witch I can't use any of include directives before the function I should write. But I can use 2 directives given as string arguments of the function . How can I `#include` that directives inside of that function?

There is my code and I have no idea how to make it work. (In the final version the `main()` part would be deleted, because the code is checked by University's program, and it has it's own `main()`)

```
//START        
void SortCount ( string first, string header1, string header2){        

    #include <header1>        
    #include <header2>    
}

int main(){    

    string hey = " ";    
    SortCount (hey, "iostream", "fstream");         
    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You are mixing what the precompiler does (including header) and what the compiler does.

Comment: The preprocessor includes (basically copy/pastes) files _before_ the code actually runs. Since the string is being provided at runtime, there is no way to include a library in this way.

Comment: By the time a function can possibly run (`constexpr` included) all preprocessor directives such as `#include` and `#define` have already been resolved.

Comment: It seems to me like you've misunderstood the assignment. But it's not clear what it might actually be asking.

Comment: Helpful reading on why this is not possible: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a static language, hence you are not allowed to add headers dynamically.

You can use gcc to include a file to your build without using #include "file.h"

```
g++ -include file.h main.cpp main.o
```

See GCC -include